# String manipulation Mutiply letters like in python

Tags: python, c++, string

In pyhton you are able to do things such as

```
word = "e" * 5
print(word)
```

To get 
"eeeee"

But when i attempt the same thing in C++ i get issues where the output doesnt contain any text heres the code im attempting

```
playerInfo.name + ('_' * (20 - sizeof(playerInfo.name)))
```

Im tyring to balence the length of the string so everything on the player list is inline with each other

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you using `std::string`?

Comment: `'_' * (20 - sizeof(playerInfo.name))` is a _numeric_ operation - that just uses the ASCII value of `_`(95).

Comment: `std::string(5, 'e')`, `std::string(20 - sizeof(playerInfo.name), '_')`?

Comment: "In pyhton you are able to do things" C++ is not Python, Python is not C++

Comment: If name is of built in char* type then all you're doing is pointer's arithmetic, where you offset to the address of memory of playerInfo.name

Comment: if `playerInfo.name` is a `std::string`, then use `playerInfo.name.length()`, in conjonction with Jarod42 proposal

Comment: Logic is logic. It doesn't change, but do not expect how you implement logic to go unchanged when moving from one language to another. Each language has different backing ideologies and idioms and serves a different purpose in the ecosystem of programming languages. You will find that often the only thing you can reliably port from one language to another is the idea behind the code, the behaviour of the program. The code itself, how you achieve the behaviour, will be different in every language and sometimes not even look remotely similar.

Comment: Like Nathan said we need to know if you're using `std::string` or if you're dealing with C-style strings (something declared as a `char *` or as `char name[]`. What type is `playerInfo.name`?

Comment: Sorry for late reply i broke something.
But no playerIndo.name is a char* 
I did suspect i was doing pointer aithmetic, im just unsure how im meant to implement what im attempting to do
I was aware my code wouldnt work but i used it as a way to show the problem i would experiance

Comment: Does `name` need to be a `char*`?  `std::string` is a lot easier to use and will make this really easy to implement.

Comment: I could make a char array and add to that an amount of times but that seems inefficent

Comment: Yes it has to be a char* as im accessing code from an external application

Comment: @ConnorBilham `Yes it has to be a char* as im accessing code from an external application` -- I will bet a cup of coffee this isn't true that it *must* be a character pointer.  First, a `char *` is just a pointer -- where did the memory that it points to come from?

Comment: Then you want to migrate a python code to a C (not C++) code. Note that even with you get a `char*`, you can build a `std::string` with that and continue with it.

Comment: It came from an external program, ive just realised its very easy for me to just create a std::string and convert the point to actual text, i feel very stupid rn lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create string with specified number of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483406/create-string-with-specified-number-of-characters)

Comment: ```
Does this answer your question? 
```
Ive seen previous people sugget that im about to test it but i have a few other bugs to fix before i can check

Comment: `Does this answer your question?`
No i just tested the program and i got an access violation error not to sure why though...

Comment: Debuggers are usually good at helping pinpoint access violations. Run the program in the debugger and wait for it to crash. The debugger will halt the execution and allow you to inspect the crash site and the backtrace that lead to the crash. Access violation is the program trying to access memory that it does not own. In this case the program likely wandered off the end of one of the arrays or tried to read from or write to an array that does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your actual problem is that you want to display names to a certain width, then don't modify the underlying data. Instead, take advantage of `ostream`'s formatting capabilities to set alignment and fill width. Underlying data should *not* be modified to cater to display. The displaying function should be able to take the underlying data and format it as required.

This is taken from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left which describes specifically the `std::left` function, but shows examples of `std::setw` and `std::fill`, which should get you what you want. You will need to `#include <iomanip>` to to use these functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char name1[] = "Yogesh";
    const char name2[] = "John";

    std::cout << "|" << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(10) << std::left << name1 << "|\n";
    std::cout << "|" << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(10) << std::right << name2 << "|\n";
}
```

Outputs

```
|Yogesh    |
|******John|
```

---

### A note on the persistence of std::cout and ostreams

Note that `std::cout` is a `std::ostream` object, and by default lives for the lifetime of your program (or for enough of your program that it's close enough to the lifetime). As an object, it has member variables. When we call `std::setfill('*')` we're setting one of those member variables (the fill character) and overwriting the default fill character. When we call `std::setw(10)` we're setting the underlying width of the stream until another function clears it.

`std::setfill`, `std::left`, `std::right` will persist until you explicitly set them to something else (they don't return to defaults automatically). `std::setw` will persist until one of (from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

```
operator<<(basic_ostream&, char) and operator<<(basic_ostream&, char*)
operator<<(basic_ostream&, basic_string&)
std::put_money (inside money_put::put())
std::quoted (when used with an output stream)
```

So `std::setw` will persist until basically the next `std::string` or `const char *` output.

Comment: i cant get this to work in my program as i dont undertand ostream very well how would i make
```std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(10) << std::left << playerInfo.name ```
Work as a char

Comment: Where do you want to display this information? To the standard output stream (`cout`) or to a file?

Comment: Does this only apply to std::cout because im using a gui interface not cli

Comment: It applies to any `ostream` object. The gui might be using an `ostream` as its method of displaying data. What library are you using?

Comment: im using ImGui, i dont believe it uses ostream as ive modified it to fit my application

Comment: @ConnorBilham Yeah I didn't see any ostreams in the ImGui github project. How do you normally output using ImGui?

Answer (score 2):

In case of repeating a **single** character, you can use [`std::string(size_type count, CharT ch)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) like this:

```cpp
std::string str(5, 'e');
std::cout << str << std::endl; // eeeee
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no overloaded * operator for std::string. You have to write a custom function

```cpp
std::string multiply_str(std::string in, size_t count)
{
    std::string ret;
    rest.reserve(in.size() * count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         rest += in;
    return ret;
}
```

Or, if it is only on character:

```cpp
std::string(your char here, how much)
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way of doing it. You should at least reserve the correct final size and if `in` is just one character (as `char`) as in OP's example, `std::string(count, in)` will already do what they want. `int` should also probably be `std::string::size_type` or `std::size_t` instead.

Comment: You are not reserving you are resizing. I suggest you to try this function and see the result (after fixing the typos ;)

Comment: Sorry about that small mistake! It should be fixed now