# Creating a compile time string repeating a char n times

Tags: c++, c++20, string-literals, compile-time, string-view

I'm using a function like this to export data in a xml file (note: silly example):

```
void write_xml_file(const std::string& path)
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals; // Use "..."sv

    FileWrite f(path);
    f<< "<root>\n"sv
     << "\t<nested1>\n"sv
     << "\t\t<nested2>\n"sv
     << "\t\t\t<nested3>\n"sv
     << "\t\t\t\t<nested4>\n"sv;
     //...
}
```

Where those `<<` take a `std::string_view` argument:

```
FileWrite& FileWrite::operator<<(const std::string_view s) const noexcept
   {
    fwrite(s.data(), sizeof(char), s.length(), /* FILE* */ f);
    return *this;
   }
```

If necessary I can add an overload with `std::string`, `std::array`, ...

Now, I'd really love to write the above like this:

```
// Create a compile-time "\t\t\t..."sv
consteval std::string_view indent(const std::size_t n) { /* meh? */ }

void write_xml_file(const std::string& path)
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals; // Use "..."sv

    FileWrite f(path);
    f<< "<root>\n"sv
     << indent(1) << "<nested1>\n"sv
     << indent(2) << "<nested2>\n"sv
     << indent(3) << "<nested3>\n"sv
     << indent(4) << "<nested4>\n"sv;
     //...
}
```

Is there someone that can give me an hint on how implement `indent()`?
I'm not sure if my idea to return a `std::string_view` pointing to a static constant buffer allocated at compile time is the most appropriate, I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: `std::string(n, '\t')` (not compile time though).

Comment: `indent<N>()` is more correct for compile-time computation.

Comment: See if `std::setw` to see if it does what you want. Otherwise, consider implementing a class that overloads `operator<<` to output the right number of characters. You can make it a template class to make the number of characters a compile-time constant if you really need to.

Comment: `consteval` is C++20, you've tagged the question as C++17. Take a decision and update.

Comment: The constructor for `std::string` that takes a char and a count is now [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for C++ 20.  Look at constructor `(2)`.

Comment: Sure this can be done, provided you make `N` happen at compile-time, but does `indent<N>` _have_ to return a `string_view` object? IMO it might make a little more sense to instead have `indent<N>(ostream&)` function that actually indents the stream. That's also even simpler to write since it just recursively appends one `'\t'` and calls `indent<N-1>` until it reaches `0`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: but `std::string` cannot be returned from `constexpr` method anyway.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The constructor for `std::string` is only `constexpr` so that it can be used in core-constant subexpressions, but you can't produce a constexpr `string` and return it to a non-constexpr context AFAIK. Like [`constexpr auto s = std::string{2, '\t'};` is illegal in C++20](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/876oGTG9c) outside of constexpr contexts, and `operator<<` for `std::ostream&` would not qualify.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not using streams (`fwrite` is the `cstdio` one), but I'm checking in now in cppreference, could give me an inspiration :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want `indent` to work at compile-time, then you will require `N` to also be a compile time value, *or* for `indent` to be called as part of a `constexpr` sub-expression.

Since this is for the purpose of streaming to some file-backed stream object `FileWrite`, the latter is out -- which means that you need `N` to be at compile-time (e.g. pass it as a template argument).

This will change your signature to:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
consteval auto indent() -> std::string_view
```

The second part of the problem is that you want this to return a `std::string_view`. The complication here is that `constexpr` contexts don't allow `static` variables -- and thus anything you create within the context will have *automatic* storage duration. Technically speaking, you can't just simply create an array in the function and return a `string_view` of it -- since this would lead to a dangling pointer (and thus UB) due to the storage going out-of-scope at the end of the function. So you will need to workaround this.

The easiest way is to use a `template` of a `struct` that holds a `static` array (in this case `std::array` so we can return it from a function):

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
struct indent_string_holder
{
    // +1 for a null-terminator. 
    // The '+1' can be removed since it's not _technically_ needed since 
    // it's a string_view -- but this can be useful for C interop.
    static constexpr std::array<char,N+1> value = make_indent_string<N>();
};
```

This `make_indent_string<N>()` is now just a simple wrapper that creates a `std::array` and fills it with tabs:

```cpp
// Thanks to @Barry's suggestion to use 'fill' rather than
// index_sequence
template <std::size_t N>
consteval auto make_indent_string() -> std::array<char,N+1>
{
    auto result = std::array<char,N+1>{};
    result.fill('\t');
    result.back() = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

And then `indent<N>` just becomes a wrapper around the holder:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
consteval auto indent() -> std::string_view
{ 
    const auto& str = indent_string_holder<N>::value;

    // -1 on the size if we added the null-terminator.
    // This could also be just string_view{str.data()} with the
    // terminator
    return std::string_view{str.data(), str.size() - 1u}; 
}
```

We can do a simple test to see if this works at compile-time, which it should:

```cpp
static_assert(indent<5>() == "\t\t\t\t\t");
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WdoTsnfnn)</kbd>

If you check the assembly, you will also see that `indent<5>()` produces the correct compile-time string as desired:

```
indent_string_holder<5ul>::value:
        .asciz  "\t\t\t\t\t"
```

---

Although this works, it would actually probably be much simpler for you to write `indent<N>()` in terms of `FileWrite` (or whatever the base class is -- assuming this is `ostream`) instead of returning a `string_view`. Unless you are doing buffered writing to these streams, the cost of writing a few single characters should be minimal compared to the cost of flushing the data -- which should make this negligible.

If this is acceptible, then it would actually be much easier since you can now write it as a recursive function that passes `\t` to your stream object, and then calls `indent<N-1>(...)`, e.g.:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
auto indent(FileWrite& f) -> FileWrite&
{
    if constexpr (N > 0) {
        f << '\t'; // Output a single tab
        return indent<N-1>(f);
    }
    return f;
}
```

This changes the use to now be like:

```cpp
FileWrite f(path);

f<< "<root>\n"sv;
indent<1>(f) << "<nested1>\n"sv;
indent<2>(f) << "<nested2>\n"sv;
indent<3>(f) << "<nested3>\n"sv;
indent<4>(f) << "<nested4>\n"sv;
```

But the implementation is much easier to grok and understand IMO, compared to producing a string at compile-time.

Realistically, at this point it might just be cleaner to write:

```cpp
auto indent(FileWrite& f, std::size_t n) -> FileWrite&
{
    for (auto i = 0u; i < n; ++i) { f << '\t'; }
    return f;
}
```

which is likely what most people would expect to read; although it does come at the minimal cost of the loop (provided the optimizer does not unroll this).

Comment: You don't need to use `index_sequence`. Much simpler to just... create an array of `char` and just `fill()` it.

Comment: @Barry Excellent suggestion -- thank you! I really need to modernize my way of writing `constexpr` code; i think I've been too heavily influenced by C++11's way of having to do things

Comment: Thank you for the insights, I'll tinker on both the excellent solutions you proposed. BTW, the arguments of a `consteval` function *must* be known at compile time, I wonder if one day the template angle bracket syntax will become obsolete.

Comment: @MatG Even though the argument of a `consteval` function must be known at compile-time, the argument itself is not considered a constant-expression (at least, not yet). This distinction is important because it means you can't use the parameter as an input to a [template non-type argument, or an array size](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eExPY35nx). So at least in the current C++20 standard, it would be impossible to produce something like a `char` array at compile-time without templates AFAIK.

Answer (score -4):

use of std::string (size_t n, char c);

see also [create-string-with-specified-number-of-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483406/create-string-with-specified-number-of-characters)

```
void write_xml_file(const std::string& path)
{

 using namespace std::string_view_literals; // Use "..."sv

 FileWrite f(path);
 f<< "<root>\n"sv
 << std::string ( 1, '\t') << "<nested1>\n"sv
 << std::string ( 2, '\t') << "<nested2>\n"sv
 << std::string ( 3, '\t') << "<nested3>\n"sv
 << std::string ( 4, '\t') << "<nested4>\n"sv;
 //...
}
```

Comment: Is it compile time?

Comment: This fails to answer the question as asked, since the question is requesting a **compile-time** string. Although `std::string` has a `constexpr` constructor that produces this, `std::string` itself is _not_ at compile-time; it can only be _used_ in `constexpr` contexts -- but not escape it. Thus using it in this way is actually producing a runtime-computed string each time.