# How to output the same number of 0's for whichever x = to

Tags: c++

For e.g. `X=12` need to get the same number of 0's added to the end of the below `var`

The output should look something like `allHeKnows = 1000000000000`

For any `X = single digit` will display the correct output, however

Not sure how to reset, or what condition to add that in order for any `X >= 10` to display the int `allHeKnows` value accordingly

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () { 
  int X, allHeKnows = 1, i=0; 
  cin >> X;
  while ((X > 0 && X <100) && (i!=X)) { 
    i++;
    allHeKnows = allHeKnows * 10;
    cout << "this is allHeKnows: " << allHeKnows << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Use a string instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12483672/4342498)

Comment: "Not sure how to reset" Well, try thinking about it: what needs to be reset? In order to qualify as "reset", what value should it have? At what point in the program flow does this need to happen in order to have it do what you want?

Comment: Recommendation Pick one Standard tag. You aren't using C++17 AND C++14 for a job this small, and you shouldn't mix and match in larger projects.

Comment: `int` may not be large enough to hold 12 digits. It is only required to hold five, but most implementations hold 10.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you, I have added the C++17 and C++14 due to a lack of knowledge, however, I have modified that accordingly
meanwhile, I have managed to solve the actual exercise as follows: 
`cout << "1";`
`while (i < x) {`
`cout << "0";`
`i++;` ;
just thought there could have been a way related to the first solution that I"ve posted, but I do now understand the limitations of `int`, thanks again :)
I'll also try and convert that to a string once I'll get there within the module

Comment: General rule of thumb: If you are not using the number for arithmetic and just using it as a sequence of digits, storing it as a string is usually the right way to go. If you have to support arbitrary lengths and no math requirements, string is almost certainly the correct solution. Sooner or later in your studies you'll have to reverse a number, and if you accept string input and stay in string, the reverse is a one-liner. If you operate on a numeric type you're using a loop and dividing, taking the modulo, and bending over backward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem that I see initially is that once you get past 10 digits you surpass the max int value allowed by c++. You would be better off converting to a string if you are trying to reach those higher numbers.

Comment: Even a float has a mantissa, limiting the accurate number of 0's a number can contain. One of the things about those big RSA numbers used for encryption is that they designedly never fit into the word size of the day. 40 bit encryption would be easy to crack on a 64 bit machine. SSE and MMX offers the ability to work with 128 bit numbers but the number oif zeros in a 128 bit number is only 38. PaulWall is right, use strings for very long numbers.

Comment: Fun fact: only the minimum size of `int` (16 bits) is set in stone by the C++ Standard. The upper size is left up to the implementation with the only requirement that it cannot be larger than `long`. Usually it's 32 bits these days, but it would be conceivable for it to be 1024 bits on a system capable of handling that size as long as `long` is at least 1024 bits. Taken to extremes, this means that you can make all of the integer types the same size. Cray used to do exactly that. Even `char` was 32 bit.

Comment: [Backing documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Signed_and_unsigned_integer_types).